# AngularJS - Scope property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radiobuttonlist

I have this HTML saved in a file.

HTML :

```
<!-- radio button 1 -->
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-group1" ng-model="radio1" value="group1">
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio-group2" ng-model="radio1" value="group2">

<!-- radio button 2 -->
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio-group3" ng-model="radio2" value="group3">
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio-group4" ng-model="radio2" value="group4">
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio-group5" ng-model="radio2" value="group5">
```

And I've created a directive.

Javascript:

```
App.directive('radioControls', [function() {
    return {    
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'radio-controls-template.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.radio1= 'group1';
            $scope.panelStyle = 'group4';
        }]
    }

}])
```

And here's the HTML where I use the attribute `radio-controls`.

```
<div class="radio-buttons-div" radio-controls>      
</div>    
<span>{{ radio1 }}</span>
<span>{{ radio2 }}</span>
```

It is working fine. But if I duplicate the entire HTML and if I click on any of the radio buttons available. All the span gets updated which the `radio1` or `radio2` inside the handlebars.

I know that we need to play on the scope. But I don't understand what or how it works or how to make it work.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BaBiCWhX6Wktu4Hr6lLD?p=preview) for a better understanding.

Comment: Learn about isolate scope

Comment: I'm looking at the angulars docs. But it's not that clear for me. Can you help me out with it?

Comment: Direct link: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an isolated scope within your directive to not change the global scope.

Use two different objects in the scope:

```
<div class="controller">
<p>
  <form>
    <radio-controls group1="d1.group1" group2="d1.group2"></radio-controls>
  </form>  
  <br />
  <span>Group 1 Value : {{ d1.group1 }}</span>
  <br>
  <span>Group 2 Value : {{ d1.group2 }}</span>
</p>
<p>
  <form>
    <radio-controls group1="d2.group1" group2="d2.group2"></radio-controls>
  </form>
  <br />
  <span>Group 1 Value : {{ d2.group1 }}</span>
  <br>
  <span>Group 2 Value : {{ d2.group2 }}</span>
</p>
</div>
```

define a isolated scope in the directive:

```
App.directive('radioControls', [function() {

return {

    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      group1: '=',
      group2: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'radio-controls-template.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.radio1= 'group1';
        $scope.panelStyle = 'group4';
    }]
}

}])
```

And use the directive scope in the template:

```
<!-- radio button 1 -->
<input type="radio" name="name" id="radio-group1" ng-model="group1" value="radio1">Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="name" id="radio-group2" ng-model="group1" value="radio2">Radio 2


<!-- radio button 2 -->
<input type="radio" name="name2" id="radio-group3" ng-model="group2" value="radio3"> Radio 3
<input type="radio" name="name2" id="radio-group4" ng-model="group2" value="radio4"> Radio 4
<input type="radio" name="name2" id="radio-group5" ng-model="group2" value="radio5"> Radio 5
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yNVDMe?p=preview

Comment: I have about n number of groups to be created. I won't be able to repeat myself by adding `d1`, `d2` to make it unique in all the groups. I was digging a bit in the isolated scope. And learnt a bit but that knowledge is not enough for me to make it dynamic.

Comment: but then use an array and ng-repeat instead. It wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: my template is a html file. How can I use `ng-repeat` in that?